# 'R' Search for values in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, stringdist

I have printed out a matrix with stringdistmatrix(c(). Works well, but now I need R to show me all cases with a value <=3. How can I search for those values in the matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `which(m<4,arr.ind=TRUE)` might be helpful.  See `?which`

Answer (score 0):

Define the output as a matrix and index?

```
d <- as.matrix(stringdistmatrix(c('foo','bar','boo','baz')))
d[d<=3]
```